# How to retrieve id's which have common values and display them together?

Tags: mysql

I'm a beginner to SQL. I have a problem, where I have to retrieve the producer id's who have 4 or more common consumers. And I want to display the 
 Producer Id's together with the count. For Example,

My sample database:
[Sample database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qapAY.png) - my sample database

sample output should be a and b, because they supply 4 parts in common (21,22,23,24).

I think, I should use groupconcat and having by right?

[Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEZvJ.png)

Comment: Can you post your table structure?  The provided example is ambiguous.

Comment: Yeah, just added the picture of it. I'm new here :|

Comment: how you can find out which have the same id. in the picture are the most ids empty

Comment: I've posted wrong picture. Sorry for that. check it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `producer_id`, COUNT(`consumer_id`) AS cnt
FROM orders
GROUP BY `consumer_id`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 4
```

Should do it.

Updated, to get the consumer count per producer:

```
SELECT `producer_id`, COUNT(`consumer_id`) AS cnt
FROM orders
GROUP BY `producer_id`
HAVING COUNT(`consumer_id`) > 4
```

Then an [inner join](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx) to get the result you want:

```
SELECT tt1.producer_id, tt2.count
from (SELECT COUNT(consumer_id) as count, producer_id from ORDERS GROUP  BY producer_id HAVING COUNT(`consumer_id`) > 4) tt1
  INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(consumer_id) as count, producer_id from ORERS GROUP BY producer_id HAVING COUNT(`consumer_id`) > 4) tt2
     on tt1.producer_id = tt2.producer_id
WHERE tt1.count = tt2.count
```

Tested and working on your sample data.

Comment: This does not appear to be correct because it is grouping on the unique values within the 'consumerID' column. This will result in an output containing 6 rows for each of the unique 'consumerID' values. As a result, it definitely will not produce the intended result set.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But, I want it as a combination like a and b together have 4 in common

Comment: Hi, I tried out your updated answer, but it is showing me the individual count. Like, a - 5
                    b-4

Comment: The code works, the first query is better, set HAVING(count) = 4 or whatever you want to match and it will show you all producer_ids with that count, you will need something like PHP to run the query, get the results then format it like 'a and b have 4 in common'.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this will help:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cusomer_id) FROM table GROUP BY pro_id HAVING COUNT(pro_id)>4
```

HAVING is a good method when you want to filter rows based on the result of aggregate functions (such as SUM and COUNT).
"GROUP_CONCAT" will ensure you get all 4 results combined in one column

Comment: This does not appear to be correct because it does not take into account the consumerID at all. This will only display 'a' as the result since it has more than 4 respective values for the 'consumerID' field.

Comment: yeah, I'm not getting any output bro :(

Comment: And I want the output as a combination, you can see in my sample output. a and b together have 4 in common

Comment: Ok, then use GROUP_CONCAT method.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table t (p varchar(1), c int);
insert into t values('a',21);
insert into t values('a',22);
insert into t values('a',23);
insert into t values('a',24);
insert into t values('b',21);
insert into t values('b',22);
insert into t values('b',23);
insert into t values('b',24);
insert into t values('c',21);
insert into t values('c',22);
insert into t values('c',24);
insert into t values('d',22);
insert into t values('d',23);
insert into t values('d',25);
insert into t values('d',26);

// Get all the producers with at least 4 consumers,
// enumerate the consumers.
select p,
       group_concat(c order by c) g,
       count(*) c
from   t
group by p having count(*) >= 4;

+------+-------------+---+
| p    | g           | c |
+------+-------------+---+
| a    | 21,22,23,24 | 4 |
| b    | 21,22,23,24 | 4 |
| d    | 22,23,25,26 | 4 |
+------+-------------+---+

// Find common producers.
select group_concat(p) as producer,
       g as "group",
       c as count from(
  select p,
         group_concat(c order by c) g,
         count(*) c
  from   t
  group by p having count(*) >= 4
) t2 group by g having count(*) > 1;

+----------+-------------+-------+
| producer | group       | count |
+----------+-------------+-------+
| a,b      | 21,22,23,24 |     4 |
+----------+-------------+-------+
```